# As a British citizen married to a non EU citizen, can we travel together to italy?

Tags: visas, italy, tunisian-citizens

I am a British citizen married to a Tunisian citizen. We live together in Tunisia and we are planning to go to Italy for holiday. My question is: is it free of charge or he need to pay fees?
What documents does he need to show to the embassy when he applies?

Answer (score 7):

If your trip is on or before March 29, the visa should be free of charge under the EU free movement regime.  If the trip is after then, it might still be free of charge, or it might not be, and on top of that there's a chance that the current Gibraltar controversy leads to a requirement for *you* to have a visa as well.  It's not really possible to say at the moment when the UK will leave the EU, or even whether, or what the arrangements will be after it leaves.